# Overly Broad Directory.EnumerateFiles() vs Multiple File.Exists()?

Tags: c#, file-io, io, directory

I am updating a program which, among other things, checks for the existence of files within a given path. The files could be located in any one of many subdirectories off of the main path. Previously, we were searching this entire path for files that matched a given pattern, but part of the update is that we now have a separate array containing a list of the files we expect to have.

Given the presence of that array, there are two options I am considering:

1. Use the same call to `Directory.EnumerateFiles(startingPath, pattern, SearchOption.Alldirectories)` and then check the results against my array (perhaps through a lambda).
2. Use multiple calls to `File.Exists()` for each member of the array.

In the average case, we are talking about 3 or fewer files in the array for any given call. In the high-end case, we are still talking about less than a dozen. Most executions will involve hundreds or thousands of calls.

This program is already a resource hog, so I definitely want to go with the most efficient method here. Which is more efficient? Is there a better way? Changing the datastructure for filenames from an array to another type is possible if that will lead to improvements.

Comment: Try both, see which is faster, and go with that.  It will depend so much on the specifics of your case, i.e. how large the directory tree is, the likelihood of finding a value, the specs of the physical storage device number of items you're searching for, etc.  Why guess when you can just try both with your actual data and *know*.  [For further reading](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the second method, a bunch of calls to `File.Exists`, and do it in a parallelized fashion. There is low throughput cost but high latency cost on `File.Exists`, so for speed you want it to be asynchronous.

Basic idea to start with:

```
var fileExists = myFilePaths
    .AsParallel()
    .ToDictionary(path => path, path => File.Exists(path));
```

(Of course, trying the first method and doing a speed comparison is completely reasonable - I'm just giving my 'best guess' and comments on the second method.)